# Grails setup in eclipse - incompatible compiler

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy

When I create a new Grails projects I receive the attached popup

[image]

Is 1.8.0.xx not a valid version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy 1.8 is introduced in Grails 2.0, though it still should work with Grails 1.3.7, but as statement says it might break.